# Grids and pointers in c

Tags: c, pointers, grid

I made this program in C where an object `R` is placed on a grid and it's supposed to move taking inputs from they keyboard. For example, thi is what happens if you press N.

```
         0 1 2
       0 - - -                      R - -                  - - -                               
       1 R - -  PRESS N -> GO UP -> - - - PRESS N AGAIN -> - - -
       2 - - -                      - - -                  R - -
```

So R makes it go up. The object has to move **around**, so when it is at [A0][B0], for example, it needs to go all the way down [A2][B0]. See above.
It will move up, down, left and right.

Right now i'm creating the function to make it move **up**, but i'm having a lot of troubles: sometimes it randomly freezes to 2:0 and 0:0 without goind up, and when it's at A = 2, instead of going up of 1, it goes to 0, although i set it to do 2-1 (to go up it has to subtract 1).

I don't understand what's causing those troubles, any advice?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define X 3
#define Y 3

struct coords{
    int a;
    int b;
};

typedef struct coords cord;

// Print the array
char printArray(char row[][Y], size_t one, size_t two, struct coords cord)
{  

   row[cord.a][cord.b] = 'X';


   // output column heads
   printf("%s", "       [0]  [1]  [2]");
   // output the row in tabular format
   for (size_t i = 0; i < one; ++i) {

      printf("\nrow[%lu] ", i);

      for (size_t j = 0; j < two; ++j) {
         printf("%-5c", row[i][j]);
      } 
   } 
} 


int moveUp(struct coords * cord);


int main(void)
{  
   struct coords cord;


   char row[X][Y] =  
      { { '-', '-', '-'},
        { '-', '-', '-'},
        { '-', '-', '-'} };


   srand(time(NULL));


   cord.a = (rand() % 3); 
   cord.b = (rand() % 3);
   printf("\nValori rand: A %d, B %d\n", cord.a, cord.b);

   // output the row

   //printf("\nrobot:%c\n", robot);
   puts("The array is:");
   printf("\n");

   printArray(row, X, Y, cord);
   row[cord.a][cord.b] = '-';


   //printArray(row, X, Y, &m, &n);
   char h;

   while(h != '3'){


    switch (h) {

      case 'N':

        moveUp(&cord);
        printArray(row, X, Y, cord);
        row[cord.a][cord.b] = '-';

        break;
    }
    scanf("%s", &h);

  }

  printf("\n");
}

int moveUp(struct coords * cord)
{

   cord->a - 1;


   if (cord->a == 2){
      cord->a - 1;
   } else if (cord->a == 1){
      cord->a - 1;
   } else if (cord->a == 0){
      cord->a + 2;
   }



   /*
   if (cord->a == 0) {
    cord-> a = 2;
   } else {
    cord->a - 1;
   }
   */

   printf("\n A = %d, B = %d\n", cord->a, cord->b);



}
```

Comment: Try debugging your code.

Comment: cord->a -1 ; what is the purpose of this line

Comment: To go up on the grid, A needs to be detracted of 1

Comment: code->a = code->a - 1; try this

Comment: It seems not to work, it goes offset, out of the grid

Comment: define the boundary of grid and use that condition in if statement and you will get your answer.

Comment: Do you mean to set an if statement to make it not go to negative numbers?

Comment: Yes, your grid must have a boundary. Otherwise how your program will know when to stop ?

Comment: It has to move round, so if it goes to boundary, it has to go the opposite part of it

Comment: OKay, but you are supposed to tell the program to go to opposite site when reaches a particular boundary.

Comment: I thought of setting if statements for it, for example when you are at 2, decrement 2 or go to 0 to go the opposite part

Comment: The modulus operator `%` has properties that should interest you.

Comment: What do you mean @jwdonahue?

Comment: I mean you should study how the modulus operator works and think about how that can be applied to your problem. Happy to nudge you, but I won't do your homework for you. Think about `(currentIndex + delta) % EXTENT`.

Comment: Let's put it simply: If you have a nonnegative integer `i` that is allowed to vary between `0` and `n-1`, inclusive, then `i = (i + 1) % n;` increments and `i = (i + n - 1) % n;` decrements `i`, with wraparound. That is, decrementing `0` yields `n-1`, and incrementing `n-1` yields `0`. This works, because `expression % n` (the modulo operator) yields the remainder after expression is divided by `n`. We just must make sure the argument is positive, and we can do that by adding `n` (unless `i < -n` already, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below code, you are checking the value of `h` before having read anything into it. If the uninitialized value of `h` happens to be `3`, then execution will not enter the while loop.

```
   char h;
   while(h != '3')
```

So read in a value into `h` and then do the check in the `while` loop.

In the `moveUp` function, you can use the [ternary conditional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) operator to assign the next position or the object `R`.

```
cord->a = (cord->a)? (cord->a - 1): 2;
```